# Naming URL patterns‎ for a forum

Tags: php, url, rest

I am creating a web forum, which of the following URL pattern you preferred and why?

```
A.

Group pages: http://forum.example.com/groups/computer
Post pages: http://forum.example.com/groups/computer/posts/123

B.

Group pages: http://forum.example.com/groups/computer
Post pages: http://forum.example.com/groups/computer/123

C.

Group pages: http://forum.example.com/computer
Post pages: http://forum.example.com/computer/123
```

Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: Not a question and purely subjective. You could turn it in to a question if you totally rephrased.

Comment: I vote for option C. I think it's better than A, because it's not clear that there's a relation between the first and second parameter. Especially when you have 10 parameters this will get confusing fast. Options B is not good, because it's inconsistent to have a relation between the first and second parameters, but have the third parameters stand all by itself. But it's not really a question...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Definitely the C
What does the computer folder stands for?

Answer (score -1):

I prefer the option B, because each element of the url has a explicite name, it's better for your SEO. And you have very good keys words in your url.

Seb